# MQTT Client Broker communication - can a malicious client masquerade as a legitimate one after being connected with credentials

Tags: mqtt, security

I would like to ask a question that I have about MQTT client broker communication. Let's say, a client C1 is connected to the broker with user name and password (with no encryption).

What happens when a new client C2 (a malicious one) tries to publish or subscribe to a topic  without actually initiating connection and pretending to be C1? Are there any means by which the server can figure out that C1 is not the one trying to communicate?

This question arises because after the connection process, the broker does not really check for credentials each time it is trying to subscribe or publish to a topic (as far as I am aware - may be wrong altogether).

Comment: perhaps you may wish to ask about credential checking instead, since that appears to be the actual knowledge gap

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As with nearly any unencrypted protocol, there is no man in the middle protection.

If this is a treat model you need to protect against then running MQTT over SSL/TLS is the solution.

Comment: Using Secure MQTT with SSL is definitely a great option. Provisioning the cryptomaterial is the hurdle we actually have. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: All you need to provide for basic TLS support is a CA certificate, assuming a long enough life time for that cert that shouldn't be a problem. Unlike having to security distribute private keys for TLS client authentication